Running web3 in NodeJs enviroment
When I attempt to import web3 in NodeJS enviroment while on the project directory I get undefined error.
> const { Web3 } = require('web3');
undefined

> const web3 = new Web3('https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/9aHCL7I90Xo_YSRD3P1PxkyMEANMyWl7')
undefined

Any ideas?

...what error? What were you expecting to see?

That is not an error. An assignment statement's value is undefined. Try web3 in the REPL and you'll see it's there.

There is a website that explains the simple and basic web3 topic and in addition, there is a video in it that explained everything in brief. That I found Learn-web3-nodejs or you can use another one website Official documentation for web3.js
I recommend visiting it. And it shows that you need to install web3 library in your project

npm install web3

(of course in your node js)
and then import to the file you are working with
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/9aHCL7I90Xo_YSRD3P1PxkyMEANMyWl7');
" And of course there are some functions you can run that I found in the documentation example code: web3 "// Import web3
const Web3 = require('web3');

// Create a new instance of web3 with the provided URL
const web3 = new Web3('https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/9aHCL7I90Xo_YSRD3P1PxkyMEANMyWl7');

// Check if web3 is connected to the network
web3.eth.net.isListening()
 .then(() => console.log('Connected to the network'))
 .catch(e => console.log('Something went wrong', e));

with a command as explained

node yourFileName.js

(you can change the name if you want), good luck
